# Ember.js setting belongsTo relationship via select menu

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Lets say I have two models, `Chapter` and `Book` (using ember-data).

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  chapters: DS.hasMany 'chapter'

App.Chapter = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr 'string'
  book: DS.belongsTo 'book'
```

I have an interface for editing a `Chapter` in which I would like to provide a select menu for specifying the parent `Book`.

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resoure 'chapters', ->
    @route 'edit', path: ':chapter_id/edit'


App.ChaptersEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) ->
    @store.find('chapter', params.chapter_id)

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.set('content', model)
    controller.set('books', @store.find('book'))
```

I grab all the `Book`s in the `ChaptersEditRoute` so that I can provide the `Ember.Select` view a `contentBinding`.

```
... form stuff

{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="books"
                    optionValuePath="content"
                    optionLabelPath="content.name"
                    prompt="Select a Book"
                    selectionBinding="book"}}

<button {{action "submit"}}>Save</button>
```

In the `ChaptersEditController` I have the `submit` action handler.

```
App.ChapterEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    submit: ->
      chapter = @get('model')
      book = chapter.get('book')
      chapter.set('book', book)
      chapter.save().then(@onCreate.bind(@), @onFail.bind(@))

  onCreate: ->
    ... implementation

  onFail: ->
    ... implementation
```

Although this does work, I'm skeptical on *how* this works.

1. The option values in the select menu are `Book` objects.
2. I'm setting the association directly based on the option value (the `Book` object).

**Is this a valid solution to setting a `belongsTo` association via a select menu?**

A second option would be to pass a `Book` ID as the option value by changing the `optionValuePath` to `content.id` instead of `content`, and adding a `value` option.

```
{{view Ember.Select contentBinding="books"
                    optionValuePath="content.id"
                    optionLabelPath="content.name"
                    value=book_id
                    prompt="Select a Book"
                    selectionBinding="book"}}
```

And update the `submit` action handler in the controller.

```
...

submit: ->
  chapter = @get('model')
  @store.find('book', chapter.get('book_id')).then (book) =>
    chapter.set('book', book)
    chapter.save().then(@onCreate.bind(@), @onFail.bind(@))
```

There are a few problems with this solution.

1. If a user doesn't change the select menu then the `book_id` will never be set and the `submit` action handler breaks.
2. We ask the store for an object that we've already loaded, which may or may not add some redundancy.

**Ultimately, I'm not sure what the "Ember way" is to set a `belongsTo` association via a select menu.**

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: This should probably be posted on Programmers instead of StackOverflow. But regardless, I think the first way you have it is better than the second way. Besides, if it works it works, right? But as a warning, be careful of Ember's select component. I ran into a few issues while doing what you're doing now, so I eventually wrote my own component that was built specifically to hold models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update belongsTo relationship via native select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631440/update-belongsto-relationship-via-native-select-element)

Comment: `Ember.Select` does not exist anymore.  See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38631440/update-belongsto-relationship-via-native-select-element/44977093#44977093) for two options to solve this problem.