# Update belongsTo relationship via native select element

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been trying to incorporate details of [Brenna O'Brien](https://twitter.com/brnnbrn)'s Ember Conf 2016 talk [`<select>`ing Good Ember Patterns](https://github.com/poteto/emberconf-2016#selecting-good-ember-patterns-by-brenna-obrien) into a project and it is working for simple attributes (in the example below `names` is an array of strings and `model.name` is an `attr( "string" )`):

```
<select onchange={{action (mut model.name) value="target.value"}}>
  {{#each names as |name|}}
    <option value={{name}} selected={{eq name model.name}}>{{name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

However, when this is applied to a `belongsTo` relationship and an array of models:

**Controller**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  titles: null,
  init(){
    this.set( "titles", this.store.peekAll( "title" ) );
  }
});
```

**Template**:

```
<select onchange={{action (mut model.title) value="target.value"}}>
  {{#each titles as |title|}}
    <option value={{title}} selected={{eq title.id model.title.id}}>
      {{title.description}}
    </option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

This fails; the relationship value is modified but it is not set to a valid title. From some analysis, it appears that the `title` model is stringified either when it is being handled by HTMLBars or when it is set as the `option.value` and this is not (cannot?) being converted back when the relationship is set.

I have currently solved it ([Ember-Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/87344e9877c6f9930619c09ee415a8e6)) by adding an action to the controller:

```
actions: {
  title( id ){
    this.set( 'model.title', this.store.peekRecord( "title", id ) );
  }
}
```

and modifying the template to call this:

```
<select onchange={{action "title" value="target.value"}}>
  {{#each titles as |title|}}
    <option value={{title.id}} selected={{eq title.id model.title.id}}>
      {{title.description}}
    </option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

However, I then need to create a function for each relationship I want to update in this way.

Is there a way to directly set a `belongsTo` relationship from the template without calling an intermediate function or resorting to add-ons? (If not then is there a DRY method of solving this?)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, until we have routable components, there is no way to do this without sending an action from the component.  Fortunately, we have `ember-route-action-helper` to help us, and this acts as sort of a shim for routable components.  (https://github.com/DockYard/ember-route-action-helper) - I know you said you wanted to avoid add-ons but this is the only "solution that does not involve defining actions in the component" available at this point in time (as far as I know). Furthermore, it's a very helpful add-on in general.  I'm using it for this use case and others.  Bonus: when the routable components feature lands, you won't really have to do any refactoring.  Anyhow, this is how I solved this problem:

**You can specify the action on the route, and use a Mixin for DRY.**  (Instead of a Mixin, you could also just extend Route and inherit from that, or you could reopen Route.  I would be opposed to reopening Route, because you are very unlikely to need this action on every single route.  Avoid bloat.)

This Mixin presumes that your model property and the belongsTo model that it references will always have the same name, so only uses one variable: `property`.  If this is not the case, you'll need to add (and pass) another parameter to `setBelongsTo()` and specify which parameter is used for `set()` and `peekRecord()`.

Tested and works on `ember-cli: 2.13.2`

**Option 1: Native Select Method**

*note: `ember-route-action-helper` add-on is required*

```
// mixins/my-mixin.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  actions: {
    setBelongsTo(model, property, value) {
      this.get('controller').get(model).set(property, this.store.peekRecord(property, value));
    }
  }
});
```

```
// routes/my-route.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import SetBelongsToMixin from 'myApp/mixins/set-belongs-to';

export default Ember.Route.extend(SetBelongsToMixin, {
  model() {
    return this.get('store')find(...);
  }
});
```

```hbs
// templates/my-route.hbs

<select onchange={{action (route-action 'setBelongsTo' 'model' 'title') value="target.value"}}>
  {{#each titles as |title|}}
    <option value={{title.id}} selected={{eq title.id model.title.id}}>
      {{title.description}}
    </option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

**Option 2: `ember-power-select` Method**

*note: `ember-route-action-helper` add-on is required*

some slight differences if using `ember-power-select` (https://github.com/cibernox/ember-power-select)

```
// mixins/my-mixin.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  actions: {
    setBelongsTo(model, property, value) {
      this.get('controller').get(model).set(property, value);
    }
  }
});
```

```
// routes/my-route.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import SetBelongsToMixin from 'myApp/mixins/set-belongs-to';

export default Ember.Route.extend(SetBelongsToMixin, {
  model() {
    return this.get('store')find(...);
  }
});
```

```hbs
// templates/my-route.hbs

{{#power-select
  options=titles
  selected=model.title
  onchange=(action (route-action 'setBelongsTo' 'model' 'title'))
  as |title|
}}
  {{title.description}}
{{/power-select}}
```

**Edit 1:** The OP makes use of `ember-truth-helpers` add-on to set the selected option.  (Or OP created their own helper for `eq`.)  The first solution here also uses this add-on.

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts and finding [the documentation for currying action arguments](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#toc_invoking-an-action) (which appears to be necessary to have multiple arguments for an action when one of them is set via the `value=` attribute) here is a DRY-er solution:

**Component**:

```
actions: {
  updateValue( attr, model, id ){
    this.set( attr, this.store.peekRecord( model, id ) );
  }
}
```

**Template**:

```
<select onchange={{action (action "updateValue" "model.title" "title") value="target.value"}}>
  {{#each titles as |title|}}
    <option value={{title.id}} selected={{eq title.id model.title.id}}>
      {{title.description}}
    </option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

(However, I'm still looking for a solution that does not involve defining actions in the component.)